# SimpleSamlPHP - Generating SP metadata

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I am using SimpleSamlPHP library to implement SAML 2.0 SSO for my client. My client has already shared their IdP metadata and I have implemented that on my end. Now they need (off course) the SP metadata from me.

SimpleSamlPHP provides a very user friendly converter (find the converter in simplesamlphp/www/admin/metadata-converter.php) that you can use to convert the IdP metadata XML into metadata (PHP) array that you would use in saml20-idp-remote configuration.

**I am looking for** a similar utility that would take details about my assertion url, single logout url etc and would generate the SP metadata file for my client. **If there is no such utility**, can someone please give me a hint on how can I go about generating the SP metadata for my client. I off course don't expect anyone to give me the full solution, just a push in the right direction is all I need.

Thanks all.

UPDATE: I am looking for the standard XML attributes that the SP metadata XML should have.

Comment: Hello, may I know how you were able to access your metadata-converter or admin console? I installed this in Codeigniter and can't seem to create a route to it.

Answer (score 6):

SP metadata is available in web console of SimpleSAMLphp (Federation tab -> Show metadata):

```
https://your_server/path_to_simplesamlphp/www/
```

or directly via URL:

```
https://your_server/path_to_simplesamlphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/sp_name_from_authsources_php
```